Library used in python lambda function trying to write to root folder
I'm trying to pull some data from yahoo fantasy using this Oauth library https://pypi.org/project/yahoo-oauth/. I upload my lambda as a docker image on ECR and the load that image on lambda. I want this function to run once a day but I am getting an error where this library seems to want to write to a root directory in the lambda environment. I know you can only write to tmp but I can't control where this library is trying to write. What are my options?
{
  "errorMessage": "[Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'secrets.json'",
  "errorType": "OSError",
  "requestId": "65a32608-80ea-4c68-923c-ec395a996da8",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/app.py\", line 56, in handler\n    oauth = OAuth2(\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/yahoo_oauth/oauth.py\", line 236, in __init__\n    super(OAuth2, self).__init__('oauth2', consumer_key, consumer_secret, **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/yahoo_oauth/oauth.py\", line 102, in __init__\n    write_data(data, vars(self).get('from_file', 'secrets.json'))\n",


You can disable that library from writing the file: https://github.com/josuebrunel/yahoo-oauth/pull/59

Thanks for finding that, appreciate it! Curious how you went about arriving at that? Just digging into the implementation? Or just a search in the issues?

I looked in GitHub at the line of source code that was throwing the error in your question, and I saw it was checking if some setting was enabled, then I searched for that setting in the documentation and found nothing, but searching in the issues found that pull request.
